# Android - Combine Two Application Into One Application Project

Tags: android

I'm making a simple tutorial android app, and I want to combine it with android game apps that I have, I want the main application is the android app tutorial then game application is the sub menu or within my application, can you tell me how to combine it

(some code to give you some idea of my code)

HomeActivity.Java:(my tutorial)

```
package com.wglxy.example.dash1;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class HomeActivity extends DashboardActivity 
{

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
}
protected void onDestroy ()
{
super.onDestroy ();
}

protected void onPause ()
{
super.onPause ();
}

protected void onRestart ()
{
super.onRestart ();
}


protected void onResume ()
{
super.onResume ();
}

protected void onStart ()
{
super.onStart ();
}

protected void onStop ()
{
super.onStop ();
}

} // end class
```

ChuchApplication.java(game application):

```
        /**
     * 
     */
    package com.wglxy.example.dash1;

    //import com.tmm.android.chuck.quiz.GamePlay;

    import android.app.Application;

    /**
     * @author rob
     *
     */
    public class ChuckApplication extends Application{
        private GamePlay currentGame;

        /**
         * @param currentGame the currentGame to set
         */
        public void setCurrentGame(GamePlay currentGame) {
            this.currentGame = currentGame;
        }

        /**
         * @return the currentGame
         */
        public GamePlay getCurrentGame() {
            return currentGame;
        }
    }
```

and here is my androidmanifest:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.wglxy.example.dash1"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/sajda"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" >
            <activity
                android:name=".HomeActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".F1Activity"
                android:label="@string/title_feature1"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <!--
                 activity
                android:name=".F2Activity"
                android:label="@string/title_feature2"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            -->
            <activity
                android:name=".F3Activity"
                android:label="@string/title_feature3"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <activity
                android:name=".F4Activity"
                android:label="@string/title_feature4"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <activity
                android:name=".BasicTutorial"
                android:label="@string/title_feature5"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />             
            <activity
                android:name=".BasicTutorial2"
                android:label="@string/title_feature5"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <activity
                android:name=".BasicTutorial3"
                android:label="@string/title_feature5"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <activity
                android:name=".BasicTutorial4"
                android:label="@string/title_feature5"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <activity
                android:name=".BasicTutorial5"
                android:label="@string/title_feature5"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <activity
                android:name=".BasicTutorial6"
                android:label="@string/title_feature5"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <!-- activity
                android:name=".SingleListItem"
                android:label="Single Item Selected" > 
            </activity>-->
            <service
                android:name=".ChuckApplication"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <activity
                android:name=".SplashActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <activity
                android:name=".QuestionActivity"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <activity
                android:name=".RulesActivity"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <activity
                android:name=".EndgameActivity"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <activity
                android:name=".SettingsActivity"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
            <activity
                android:name=".AnswersActivity"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.D1" />
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

can anyone help me what to do? 
any confusion please comment me and i will try to help you.

Comment: did you get solution for this.

Comment: no, in the end I choose to recreate everything from the scratch and implement every method that has exist from every application code.

Comment: I implemented with different approach.

Answer (score 1):

there is two approch:

1)you can make game project as a library and through the intent you can call game project main activity but define game project main activity in your home project manifest file .

2) you can create a new package for game project  in home project and copy all the classes and related files of game project  into that package ..remember you copy all the xml files of game project in layout folder and all game project activity declare in your home project manifest file.

Comment: for option 2 i already did that for few times but the result is always like cannot access my class from game package.

and for the first option i may be don't know the proper way to include the library of my game app to my main app because every time  i do that my main project is always give me exclamation mark

Comment: follow these links for adding library projects http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-creating-android-compliant-libraries/ http://androidblogger.blogspot.in/2010/09/android-library-projects.html